# Relation of adaptor supply with the EMC/EMI of the product

Tags: emc, testing, certification, compliance

I was wondering regarding how the input of the adaptor affects the EMC/EMI of the Device. We are going to change the adaptor of our lab stirrer from **Input : 230V,50Hz,0.6A & Output : 24V,1.5A** to **Input : 230V,50Hz,1.5A & Output : 24V,1.5A.**
So in this scenario as the input ampere changes from 0.6A to 1.5A would that have any effect on the EMC/EMI of the device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: they will differ slightly..You won't notice it unless you run some very EMI sensitive applications. The ratings you provided tell nothing about EMI.

Comment: Typically during formal EMC testing that includes a mains adapter, you are required to specify the exact model of the adapter to be used and it will be written into the EMC report.

Comment: Yes Lundin that's true. But does that mean we are bound to use the same adaptor from the same brand? As in our case we outsource them. But as they are UL certified isn't it possible to use power adaptor manufactured by another company with same specs & ul certification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different power supply will have different EMI/EMC properties. The numbers on the labels cannot be used to determine if the new one is better or worse regarding EMI/EMC.

Comment: So does that mean if the adaptor supplier changes then its properties will also change? Like if input & output of two adaptors are same (Regarding I/P & O/P rating)  with same certifications like UL/ETL then the EMC/EMI of both adaptor would differ?

Comment: Of course they will differ. They are different power supplies, designed differently with different components. Even two identical power supplies may differ because their internal components are not ideal and have tolerances. So they might not be different in a way that matters. Just like you buy a pack of resistors, they are all different within certain limits but within these limits they are said to be the same component. Still, if they have the same certifications, they should be within same limits. Unless the adapters are fakes.

Comment: Thanks Justme for the information.